# Node version issue with react-native

Tags: reactjs, npm, version, native

I'm running react-native init on osx and gets the following error:
*You are currently running Node v0.10.30 but React Native requires >=4. Please use a supported version of Node.*

But when running brew upgrade node it say: *node 6.8.1 already installed*.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, had problems with the node installation. Finally uninstalled node by removing all related directories and running the following:

rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew uninstall node
brew install node --without-npm
echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh

Comment: consider using `nvm` https://github.com/creationix/nvm . It does better job of managing node and doesn't install node globally so you can easily juggle with versions.